# SQL WHERE statement with IF clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am creating a table that stores cars entering the parking lot and also leaving the parking lot. I'm working on a software that handles these cars and removes them from the list once it's done.

My software interacts with cameras that have license plate recognition on board, so it's possible that I don't get a pair of datasets with the car entering and leaving the parking lot. I want to create a view for these datasets.

The view has to list rows of cars that have entered the parking lot (Fahrtrichtung = 0) but didn't leave it afterwards and it also has to lists rows of cars that left the parking lot (Fahrtrichtung = 1) but (according to the database) didn't enter the parking lot previously. I also want the script to only return datasets that are from the previous day and older to make sure that I only get the cars that my software couldn't match and not just cars that are really just still on the parking lot.

This is my sample data set:
[image: List of all cars that entered or left the parking lot]

And this is my desired result data set:
[image: Desired results]

And this is the current script for the view:

```
SELECT id, ParkplatzId, Kennzeichen, Zeitpunkt, EingebuchtInMietservice, Foto, Fahrtrichtung, IstValidiert
FROM dbo.Fahrzeuge AS CurrentTable
WHERE (NOT EXISTS
    (    SELECT id, ParkplatzId, Kennzeichen, Zeitpunkt, EingebuchtInMietservice, Foto, Fahrtrichtung, IstValidiert
        FROM dbo.Fahrzeuge AS PreviousTable
        WHERE   (CurrentTable.Kennzeichen = Kennzeichen) AND (CurrentTable.Fahrtrichtung = 1) AND (Zeitpunkt > CurrentTable.Zeitpunkt)
    OR
                (CurrentTable.Kennzeichen = Kennzeichen) AND (CurrentTable.Fahrtrichtung = 0) AND (CurrentTable.Zeitpunkt > Zeitpunkt)))
```

This is the only script i came up with that SQL didn't complain about. I noticed that I forgot to add the date limitation. However it does not as intended anyway and I hope that you can help me make that script work.

Comment: There's no IF clause. IF is a flow control statement. If you want to return different values based on a condition you need to use `CASE WHEN` or `IIF`. The query you want is probably far simpler than you think though. You can LEFT JOIN `Fahrzeug` to itself on equal `Kennzeichen` and different IDs. All rows with no matching entry/exit will have NULL on the right. You can add the conditions you want after that, eg `Zeitpunkt` before today

Comment: is it not possible for someone to park his car there for a few days ?

Comment: You would find more people willing to give this a go, if you would provide the sample data as text in stead on an image. Nobody wants to type over all that data from an image to make a test table

Comment: It's generally better to use regular AND/OR constructions instead of CASE/IIF/etc in the WHERE clause.

Comment: and what if someone parks 2 or 3 times there on the same day ?

Answer (score 0):

I think that this query will give you all the differences :

```
WITH
T1 AS
(
SELECT *, LAG(Zeitpunkt) OVER(PARTITION BY Kennzeichen ORDER BY Zeitpunkt) AS LAST_MOVMENT 
FROM   T
)
SELECT * 
FROM   T1 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN T1 AS T2 
          ON T1.Kennzeichen = T2.Kennzeichen 
          AND T2.LAST_MOVMENT = T1.Zeitpunkt
          AND T1.Fahrtrichtung = T2.Fahrtrichtung
```